# Can something plural infer 'any' even though there's no 'any'?

Tags: determiners

If a saying 'cars are broken' is true, can it mean one car is broken as 'any/some cars are broken' is? Or should I use any/some?

Comment: By the way, Your question misuses 'infer'. A Tom Sharpe 'Wilt' novel explained the difference. **Policeman:** Are you inferring I’m an idiot? **Wilt:** No, I’m implying you’re an idiot. You see, the listener infers, the speaker implies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we don't describe a car as 'broken'. If the engine doesn't work, it has *broken down.*

*Cars* is plural and cannot mean one car.

> The car has broken down.
>
> The cars have broken down.

Does this help with what you were trying to say?